# Near protocol helper url for mainnet using near-api-js

Tags: helper, nearprotocol

I am working on the back-end for a multi-coin wallet and I have provided support for NEAR protocol using near-api-js but I'm stuck on setting a helper url for the mainnet network. I initially used https://helper.nearprotocol.com but it seems it's a helper url for generating accounts on testnet. I switched to https://helper.mainnet.near.org but accounts cannot be generated using this helper. Is there any other way accounts can be generated on the mainnet network using the near-api-js sdk?

Answer (score 2):

You have to fund accounts on mainnet to be able to create them. On testnet helper basically is running a faucet to fund accounts, it’s not available on mainnet.

What you can do to create `.near` accounts is to call `create_account` method, see example here https://github.com/near/near-wallet/blob/1fc30e26019613db0091683886615e5d4e903873/src/utils/wallet.js#L359